# Paramiko session times out, but i need to execute a lot of commands

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko, cisco, cisco-ios

I'm working on a script (python 2.7) that is wotking with a remote device running Cisco IOS, so I need to execute a lot of commands through ssh.
Few commands have no output and some of them have, and I want to recieve the output. It goes something like this:

```
import paramiko
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(self._ip, port=22, username=username, password=password
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('command with no output')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('command with no output')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('command with output')
sh_ver = stdout.readlines()
```

The thing is `exec_command` is causes the channel to close and it can’t be reused, but it's not possible for me to open a new channel in order to execute another command, because this is a session of commands that in the end I need to get the output.

I've tried to execute the commands this way as well:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('''
command
command
command
''')
output = stdout.readlines()
```

but this way, `output` is empty. And even if it would'nt, I need to perform a few checks on the `output` and then continue the session where I stopped.

So what do I need? A way to manage this ssh connection without closing it or starting a new one, and to easily recieve the output from the command.

Thanks in advance, Miri. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `invoke_shell()`. For example:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
... ...
chan = ssh.invoke_shell() # starts an interactive session

chan.send('command 1\r')
output = chan.recv()

chan.send('command 2\r')
output = chan.recv()
... ...
```

The `Channel` has many other methods. You can refer to the [document](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.7/api/channel.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly chain the commands together, as in a shell script:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('''
command1
&& command2
&& command3
''')
```

Comment: oh, okay.. but as i said, is it possible to check the output and then continue in the same session this way?

Comment: @MiriAdj: I know you said `exec_command()` can only be used once per session, but I don't think that's true.  Is your point that you want to "continue" the same chain of commands?  It would really help if you were more specific about what the commands are.

Comment: yes, it's a chain of commands.. the commands are for a cisco device, so these are some settings and then i get an output..